# Black screen with previously working ARCore apk file

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore, ar-foundation

SPECIFIC ISSUE ENCOUNTERED

I had this AR core (made in unity) application working February 6th and today (Feb. 15) I am met with a black screen once I open it as if the app never loads -- I'm met with a "app is not responding" message when waiting and I can choose to wait or close the app. I've uninstalled and reinstalled ARCore to try and fix the issue with no luck. I've also updated to the latest version of android and I've reinstalled the apk and newer apks of the same application and I get the same exact issue.

Users in the following unity forum seem to have reported what I believe is most similar to my issue here, but apparently this was resolved by Google devs this January: Unity Forum, ARCore and ARFoundation. Has anyone else experienced something similar? How might I get around this?

VERSIONS USED

```
Android Studio: 4.0.1
ARCore XR plugin in unity version: 3.1.1
Device manufacturer, model, and O/S: Google pixel 7, android 14
Google Play Services for AR (ARCore) version: 1.41.233110993
```